# Cannot install virtualenv using pip

Tags: python

I first installed distribute, then pip with easy_install but when I run:
    `sudo pip install virtualenv`

I get these error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 8, in ? sys.exit(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 345, in load_entry_point
  return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2381, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2087, in load
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.4.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in ?
from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.4.egg/pip/util.py", line 17, in ?
from pip.vendor.distlib import version
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.4.egg/pip/vendor/__init__.py", line 8
from __future__ import absolute_importSyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the    beginning of the file
```

I do not know what to do to install virtualenv properly now?

Comment: I think you should install it with never version of Python, 2.4 is really old.

Comment: @Andrey never version?

Comment: @arulmr newer of course

Comment: What's the point of using 'sudo' with 'virtualenv' ? Did you activate the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using Python 2.4 - try creating the virtualenv with a version of Python which includes [`from __future__ import absolute_import`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) (Python 2.5 or later).

You can specify which Python to use like this:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: I only have python 2.4 installed now. I am running a CentOS so I can not update python, but only install a newer version in parallel from what I read. Assuming I have successfully installed  python 2.6 outside of /usr/bin, how can I try to install virtualenv then?